# How to delete or remove the store?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-community

[image]I have a magento website in which the store structure is:

```
All Store Views    
Main Website  
 Main Website Store  
 Default Store View  
 Main Website Store  
 English
 Main Website Store  
 English
```

I have accidentally created them while importing the products and order. now i am not getting how to remove them and i only want single store on my website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `System->Store management`, click on the name of the store view you want to remove and you should see a `Delete` button on the top right corner. That should delete your store view. There is an intermediary page that asks you if you want to back-ul the store before deleting it. I suggest to back up your entire database before starting anything, then just skip that step.
**[EDIT]**
You can only delete the store views that are not used as default in their store groups.
so you should edit the store group, and change the default store view for it.
Same goes for store groups. You cannot delete one that are default in their website.

Comment: Hi Marius, I have tried the solution provided but i can not see the delete button there. i have added the screen to manage store view.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added what I missed the first time.

Comment: So in my case (i have mentioned the structure in the question) . how should i delete ?

Comment: I have checked the table core_group, here we have 4 store groups : default, Main Website Store, Main Website Store, Main Website Store with group id 0,1,2,3.

Comment: Thank you Marius. I did it though i used database for that. I need to ask you one more thing i have three flat tables for product and also for category but now i have only one store . Is it ok ?

Comment: The flat tables are generated one for each store view. You can even delete all of them and run a reindex process. It will create the tables you need.

Comment: Done!! i removed the flat tables and ran reindex process and now i have one store and one flat table. Thanks Again Marius

Answer (score 0):

Goto> System> Manage Store> Click on the store you want to delete and delete it from button given in top right corner.

It Also asks you for backup of database(if you have not taken before then take).